# VScode remote containter debug unable to find malloc.c

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, glibc

I have been trying to debug C++ code via VScode on a remote docker container. While this is working for 2 of my other college's it isn't for me. We both use the same docker image. So I suspect it's something in my VScode, but what I do not know.

I get the following error when debugging the source code.

> Unable to open 'malloc.c': Unable to read file 'vscode-remote://attached-container+7b22636f6e7461696e65724e616d65223a222f637070616e74227d/build/glibc-S9d2JN/glibc-2.27/malloc/malloc.c' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file 'vscode-remote://attached-container+7b22636f6e7461696e65724e616d65223a222f637070616e74227d/build/glibc-S9d2JN/glibc-2.27/malloc/malloc.c').

I can "fix" this by extracting glibc in /build/, but I would rather have it fix forever and not have the same issue with another docker container (possible). Glibc is installed in the Docker container at /usr/src/glibc. I found it by running `find / -iname glibc`.

To run the application from VScode on the remote docker container, I use this launch.json file:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch Program",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/src/application",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build/src",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Not sure if this information is necessary but it cant do harm.

- host: Windows 10
- docker container: ubuntu 18:04
- visual studio code version: 1.55.0

Hopefully, this is enough information to resolve the issue I'm facing.